# Flexible urethane additives in epoxies

Tags: epoxidation

For those who understand plastics and epoxies in particular, curious to know if I can add a correctly proportional amount of flexane urethane to epoxy paint without worrying about compatibility issues. IOW is there any non-typical or particular ingredient in epoxy that might prevent successful mixing of the two?

For clarity, I am using epoxy paint for a waterproof top coating on my rv roof, but would like to ensure it is a bit rubberized and not too brittle. Devcon flexane addition seems to be the answer but I can't find any guidelines for the DIYer.

Please go easy if this question is too general in the area of chemistry, seems like this is the correct forum, and thanks for any info. If you have personal experience working in the chemistry of urethanes, you may have valuable knowledge on this.

Product links:

[https://www.amazon.com/Olympic-Poxolon-Two-Coat-Epoxy-Swimming/dp/B07BLMHKBK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BLMHKBK)
https://www.reynoldsam.com/product/flexer-epoxy-flexibilizer/

Comment: Links to what you wanna use? Anyway, it doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Added the links, thanks for pointing out and for the input. I'd like to know if it's chemically fine or a gamble to do this. Seems it could reasonably go either way.